# Typescript Import Type As ( Duplicate Interface Names )

Tags: typescript

I have two types with the same name I need to import into a component.

Is something like this acceptable in typescript?

```
import type { Variant as FooVariant } from '$s/foo/types';
import type { Variant as BarVariant } from '$s/bar/types';

export type CompositeType= {
 foo: FooVariant;
 bar: BarVariant;
}
```

Comment: The code you posted works just fine. Have you tried it?

Comment: I guess I should have better worded my question I want to know if it's acceptable. I don't fully understand what TS does during the compile so I don't want to do something that will cause issues as my program grows.

Comment: @user10012, it works, so its a deisgn choice. unless you're extending Variant into foo or bar, i wont do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need it because you are using 2 third-party libs that use the same class/object name, then It's perfectly valid, even necessary. The import rename [is documented](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import-a-single-export-from-a-module) as part of the language.

On the other hand, if the rename is on your own code then I would change the name in the original file (if that file is part of your project). Exporting the same artifact name in 2 different files (in the same project) It's a source of potential issues, When you try to import with the IDE you need to choose the proper one and It's easy to get wrong, besides the resulting code in the modules that consume that object is not clear, you need to check the `import { ... } from '...'` line to known what are you using exactly.